# WCFExtras - unable to get soapheader value in or out across service

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I am tying to use [WCFExtra](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) for soapheader. I have added

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <!-- Declare that we have an extension called WSDL Extras-->
    <add name="wsdlExtensions" type="WCFExtras.Wsdl.WsdlExtensionsConfig, WCFExtras, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

to my service config file and I have added the SoapHeaders and SoapHeader attributes... I have set the value on the server side exactly like in the sample --

```
        [OperationContract]
    [SoapHeader("MyHeader", typeof(Header), Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
    string In();


        public string In()
    {
        Header soapHeader = SoapHeaderHelper<Header>.GetInputHeader("MyHeader");
        if (soapHeader != null)
        {
            return soapHeader.Value;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

on the client side I have

```
        <metadata>
          <wsdlImporters>
            <extension type="WCFExtras.Soap.SoapHeaderImporter, WCFExtras" />
          </wsdlImporters>
        </metadata>
```

And

namespace Client.MyService
{
    public partial class MyService
    {
        public Header MyHeader
        {
            get
            {
                return InnerChannel.GetHeader("MyHeader");
            }
            set
            {
                InnerChannel.SetHeader("MyHeader", value);
            }
        }
    }
}

```
            Console.WriteLine("Testing In()");
        serviceClient.MyHeader = new Header() {Value = "in"};
        string someValue = serviceClient.In();

        Console.WriteLine("The return is = " + someValue);
```

I do not see any error on the call but on the service side, I am not able to get the value I passed in the soapHeader on the client side. The same thing happens with a SoapHeader out. Can anyone please help me figure this out? What am I missing?